# Longlasting Macport installation

Tags: macos, mac, macports

I use Macports on Mac OS X to install some software.

But there are somethings that I find very strange. For instance, yesterday I installed some app and it needed to get gcc43 and compile completely from source! It took a lot of time, although now everything works right.

I understand that compilation of everything in the gentoo spirit is something nice, but in the Mac case, not necessary. There are ony sole hardware variations, so it will be easier to get the binaries.

I wonder if Macports can be forced to get the binaries when available and therefore avoid these time consuming compilations.

Thanks

Comment: Here are many MacPorts packages that are prebuilt: http://lavergne.gotdns.org/macports/

MacPorts can make use of them by following the instructions on the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment, macports does not support binary retrieval. However they are taking wide steps toward that end. Hopefully Google's Summer of Code will have some results for this and other improvements we've all been waiting for in macports.

Comment: Here are many MacPorts packages that are prebuilt: http://lavergne.gotdns.org/macports/

Answer (score -1):

At the moment, there are just not enough resources available to implement binaries as a feature. Please refer to this [FAQ entry](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#whynotxyz).

Comment: As of the release MacPorts 2.0, binary archives are available. Unfortunately, they are for Snow Leopard only at the moment as the project only has one sponsored build bot.